# Angular wildcard string comparison in html

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

This might be a very basic question and I know various ways to accomplish what I want. But, I would like to know if it is possible to use wildcards in *ngIf comparisons.

Imagine following code:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="test == 'teststring'">

</ng-container>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to for example use:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="test == '*teststring'">

</ng-container>
```

So that it could be 0teststring or 1teststring.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `test.endsWith('teststring')`. However, calling functions in the template is bad, because they are called on every tick. Use a [pure pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#detecting-pure-changes-to-primitives-and-object-references) instead:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'endsWith', pure: true })
export class EndsWithPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(a_sString: string, a_sEndsWith: string): boolean {
    return a_sString.endsWith(a_sEndsWith);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
*ngIf="test | endsWith:'teststring'"
```